# Loop setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, setinterval

I'm not sure why the interval isn't looping. I've followed tutorials exactly but not luck. Suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');  
    }, 2000);
});
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pa7aU/3/

Comment: When it gets to the last element, there's no `.next()`, so it has nothing to add the class to.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

One possible <s>ugly</s> solution:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $current = $(".current").removeClass("current"),
        $next = $current.next();

    if ($next.length)
        $next.addClass("current");
    else
        $current.siblings(":first").addClass("current");
}, 2000);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pa7aU/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $li = $('ul li'), i = 0, l = $li.length;
    setInterval(function() {
        $li.removeClass('current').eq(i % l).addClass('current');
        i++;
    }, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chg4J/

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the last element, you need to go back to the beginning, not use `.next()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var next = $('.current').removeClass('current').next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = $("li:first");
        }
        next.addClass('current');
    }, 2000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pa7aU/6/)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I knew what I had to do but trouble coding it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at the last `li`, `next()` doesnt go to the first.

An easy fix is to add that after :

```
if($('.current').length <= 0) $('li:first').addClass('current');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pa7aU/5/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something new to the mix:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('li').eq(($('.current').removeClass('current').index() + 1) % $('li').size()).addClass('current');
    }, 200);
});
```